# ¿Cómo convertir de pptx a video en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito convertir un pptx que he editado en java a un video desde el Netbeans, pero no sé cómo puedo hacerlo. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco.

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta es como hacer esa conversion con codigo? Desde PowerPoint puedes exportar un ppt a video : Export > Create a video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para convertir de un Power Point a video lo primero que se puede hacer es convertir en .png

```
  public static void crearPNG() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
      FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("tiempo.pptx");
      XMLSlideShow pptx = new XMLSlideShow(is);

      Dimension pgsize = pptx.getPageSize();

      List<XSLFSlide> slides = pptx.getSlides();
      for (int i = 0; i < slides.size(); i++) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width,pgsize.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

        graphics.setColor(Color.white);
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height);
        graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));

        XSLFSlide slide = slides.get(i);

        slide.draw(graphics);

        File pngFile = new File("images/", "slide-" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ") saving slide to " + pngFile.getName());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pngFile);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
        pptx.write(out);
        out.close();      

    }

      pptx.close();

}
```

Luego se crea un video con estas imagenes

```
public static void crearVideo() throws IOException {

    AWTSequenceEncoder enc = AWTSequenceEncoder.create25Fps(new File("test.mp4"));

    int framesToEncode = 300;

    for (int i = framesToEncode / 2; i < framesToEncode; i++) {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("images/slide-1.jpg"));
        BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/slide-2.jpg"));
        BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/slide-3.jpg"));
        BufferedImage img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/slide-4.jpg"));
        BufferedImage img4 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/slide-5.jpg"));
        enc.encodeImage(img);
        enc.encodeImage(img1);
        enc.encodeImage(img2);
        enc.encodeImage(img3);
        enc.encodeImage(img4);

    }
    enc.finish();
}
```

Comment: Te comento que responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer]